# Show real-time contents of a file in powershell

Tags: powershell, io

I have a powershell tab that I would like to run  a command on and have it start scrolling the contents of a log file as it is updated. I don't want it to exit (until I ctrl+c) and just continue scrolling the file as it is updated. How would I do this?

I've thought of [using a file watcher](http://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/a-tail-command-in-powershell/) but I would have to program the logic for determining the lines added and it just seems overall inefficient and like there's an easier way to go.

Answer (score 16):

You can do:

```
get-content file -wait
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this tip! This is kinda like *nix's tail -f which is fantastic!

Comment: And if you have a large log file to begin with try this in PowerShell V3 `get-content -tail 10 -wait foo.log`.  And for V2 there is always `Get-FileTail -Follow` in PSCX.  :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it is very slow... when having `tail -f` and `get-content -wait` side-by-side, you can see the first showing changes real-time, while the second is painfully printing big blocks every once in a while.